# Save Multiple Records Simultaneously with a single AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using jQuery Sortable to drag cards between lists, like Trello. When the user is finished interacting with a card, I need to save all cards in that list.

I'm currently doing it with an each loop, looping over all items of that type and saving each one with an AJAX request.

```
ui.item.parent('.js-CardsContainer').children('.js-CardContainer').each(function() {
  var list_id = $(this).closest('.js-List').data('id');
  var order = $(this).index();
  var id = $(this).find('.js-Card').data('id');

  console.log(order);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/cards/" + id,
    type: "PATCH",
    data: {
      card: {
        list_id: list_id,
        order: order
      }
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      //
    }
  });
});
```

It seems to work for lists with just a few cards. But when 5+ cards are being saved, some of them fail. I guess that's because separate AJAX requests are being used for each card?

So, I think I need to combine all AJAX requests into a single request? I have no idea how to do that though. Can anyone help?

This is going to my controller update action which looks like this

```
def update
    @card = Card.find(params[:id])

    if @card.update_attributes(shared_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js   {}
            format.json { render json: @card, status: :created, location: @card }
        end
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your logic so that you provide `data` with an array of `card` objects, like this:

```
var cards = ui.item.parent('.js-CardsContainer .js-CardContainer').map(function() {
    return {
        list_id: $(this).closest('.js-List').data('id'),
        order: $(this).index
    }
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: "/cards/",
    type: "PATCH",
    data: { cards: cards },
    success: function(resp){
        //
    }
});
```

You then simply need to amend your server side logic to handle the array of cards instead of a single instance.

Comment: Would the url then be "/cards" instead of "/cards/" + id?

Comment: Yes - that would be more accurate. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rory, do you know how I could update the server side logic? I'm using Rails, I've added my controller logic to the question.

Comment: I've never used Rails, sorry. You'd probably be best starting a new question for that. I'd have thought a loop through the `cards` parameter would be enough though.